# R: I set stringsAsFactors = F, but still get an "invalid factor level, NA generated" error

Tags: r

Please can someone help me with this problem? Any suggestion is greatly appreciated!

I started with:

```
A <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors = F)
A <- edit(A)
```

Then I filled in some values for A so it looks like this:

```
A
  var1  var2
1    a x,y,z
2    b   p,q
3    c   g,h
```

My goal is to get a data frame in this form:

```
  var1  var2
1    a     x
2    a     y
3    a     z
4    b     p
5    b     q  
6    c     g
7    c     h
```

This is how I tried to implement it:

```
A2 <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors = F)
for(i in 1:nrow(A)){
  if(grepl(",", A[i,2])){
    split <- unlist(strsplit(A[i,2], ","))

    for(j in 1:length(split)){
        newrow <- c(A[i,1],split[j])
        A2 <- rbind(A2, newrow)
    }
  }else{
    A2 <- rbind(A2, A[i,])
  }
}
```

But I get warning msgs:

```
Warning messages:
1: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = "y") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
2: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = "z") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
3: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = "b") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
4: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = "p") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
5: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = "b") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
6: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = "q") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
7: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = "c") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
8: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = "g") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
9: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = "c") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
10: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = "h") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

Comment: There are several recent Q&A which provide different ways to reach your goal: e.g. [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24562786/separate-values-in-a-column-of-a-dataframe-and-melt/24562914#24562914), [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24249351/can-i-split-this-dataframe-up-so-that-theres-a-new-row-for-each-item-in-some-co/24255502#24255502), and [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24595421/how-to-strsplit-data-frame-column-and-replicate-rows-accordingly/24595552#24595552)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that `stringsAsFactors` isn't a property that a `data.frame` remembers. That's only used during the initial data.frame creation and applies to all the values you pass as parameters. It does not at all affect future values you may add.

Also you're going to have problems `rbind`ing to a data.frame with no columns. R likes to make sure that column names match up and such when using `rbind` and clearly this will not be the case. Plus when you are `rbind`ing to a data.frame, it converts the object to a data.frame and then tries to add the value but this time you can't set `stringsAsFactors` so it uses the default (TRUE). You would to create your own data.frame explicitly with character columns. Here's one way you could re-write your loop

```
A2 <- data.frame(var1=character(), var2=character(), stringsAsFactors = F)
for(i in 1:nrow(A)){
  if(grepl(",", A[i,2])){
    split <- unlist(strsplit(A[i,2], ","))

    for(j in 1:length(split)){
        newrow <- c(var1=A[i,1],var2=split[j])
        A2 <- rbind(A2, data.frame(as.list(newrow), stringsAsFactors=F))
    }
  }else{
    A2 <- rbind(A2, A[i,])
  }
}
```

That being said, the [cSplit helper function](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/11380733) is useful for this type of stuff if you don't mind the dependency on `data.table`.

You might also do something like

```
A2 <- do.call(rbind, with(A, Map(expand.grid, 
     var1 = var1, 
     var2 = strsplit(var2, ",")
)))
```

with base functions to do the splitting and binding with base functions without needed a loop.